# Puppeteer performance timeline?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Is there a way to record a [performance timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/) for tests run with Puppeteer?

[image: performance timeline]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/imgs/recalculate-style.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use [`page.tracing`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-tracing) methods like in this example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.tracing.start({ path: 'trace.json' });
  await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org');
  await page.tracing.stop();

  await browser.close();
})();
```

And then load `trace.json` file in Chrome Performance tab. If you want more details [here is](https://michaljanaszek.com/blog/test-website-performance-with-puppeteer#extractDataFromNetworkTrace) an article with a chapter dedicated to analyzing page tracing.

Comment: Is there a way to generate a report from this JSON file(trace.json), as it contain lots of telemetry data?